# Expanding selection to the current word with SlateJS

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, slatejs

With Slatejs (v0.47) how do I expand the current selection (starting off collapsed) to encompass the current word?

So (assuming `[]` indicates the current section)

If I start of with

```
this is some te[]xt
```

How do I programmatically expand the selection to

```
this is some [text]
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually got this working.

```
export const word_selection = (editor) => {
  const {value} = editor
  const {selection, startText} = value
  const {start, isExpanded} = selection

  if (isExpanded) {
    return value.fragment.text
  }
  const {text} = startText
  const {offset} = start
  let left = text.slice(0, offset).search(/\S+$/)
  if (left === -1) {
    // character before the cursor is a space, selection starts at the cursor
    left = offset
  }
  let right = text.slice(offset).search(/\s/)
  if (right < 0) {
    // character after teh cursor is a space, selection ends at the cursor
    right = text.length
  } else {
    right = right + offset
  }
  if (left === right) {
    // nothing to select
    return ''
  }
  editor.moveAnchorBackward(offset - left).moveFocusForward(right - offset)
  return value.fragment.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me who comes across this old question while searching, here is the modern solution I ended up finding:

```
Transforms.move(editor, {
  unit: 'word',
  reverse: true,
  edge: 'anchor'
})

Transforms.move(editor, {
  unit: 'word',
  edge: 'focus'
})
```